# Docker compose v2 containers not finding each other (though v1 does)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Trying to learn Docker, I am having trouble getting two containers to see each other. When using docker-compose version 2 formatted files, I receive errors trying to reach the database from the front end. I tried what I thought would be a foolproof approach--[using the WordPress example straight from the Docker website](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/). Using that exact example, the database cannot be found by the wordpress container. This is the error it displays:

```
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22
Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known in - on line 22
MySQL Connection Error: (2002) php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known
```

I boiled it down to a simple example to show a working version 1 file and non-working version 2 file. The only difference between the two is the removal of the version number and the "services" grouping.

Version 1 docker-compose file that DOES work

```
web:
  image: wordpress
  links:
    - mysql
  environment:
    - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
  ports:
    - "8080:80"
mysql:
  image: mysql:5.7
  environment:
    - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
    - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
```

Version 2 docker-compose that does NOT work

```
version: '2'
services:
  web:
    image: wordpress
    links:
      - mysql
    environment:
      - WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=password
    ports:
      - "8080:80"
  mysql:
    image: mysql:5.7
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=wordpress
```

I'm not actually trying to run WordPress with these settings, just trying to figure out why a docker-compose version 2 file does not work when the exact same file, formatted as a version 1 file, does work. I have tried many other example applications that connect to a database and I can get none of them to work.

Environment I am using:

```
$ uname -a
Linux vir-docker 4.4.0-62-generic #83-Ubuntu SMP Wed Jan 18 14:10:15 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ docker -v
Docker version 1.13.1, build 092cba3
$ docker-compose -v
docker-compose version 1.11.1, build 7c5d5e4
```

Comment: Probably improved security and/or networking in version 2. You also need to set the MySQL host and port to the name of the service `mysql`.

Comment: The example on the [docker website](https://docs.docker.com/compose/wordpress/) has the MySQL host and port set and even that does not work.

Comment: version: '3' works for me... but not 2

Answer (score 1):

This must be a config issue.   I executed your exact version 2 file (only changed the published port).   Spun it up via:

```
 docker-compose up
```

Switched to another shell, and entered the web container.

```
 docker exec -it web_1 /bin/bash

 root@d089d5b25d99:/var/www/html# ping mysql
 PING mysql (172.18.0.2): 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.080 ms
 64 bytes from 172.18.0.2: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.082 ms
```

Web can ping mysql just fine.  Now let's try the mysql container:

```
 docker exec -it mysql_1 /bin/bash

 root@c8b13ff81973:/# ping web
 PING web (172.18.0.3): 56 data bytes
 64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.081 ms
 64 bytes from 172.18.0.3: icmp_seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.083 ms
```

It can ping the web container just fine.

Comment: Do you happen to have the same versions of docker and docker-compose? The VM I am using for this test was spun up for the sole purpose of playing with Docker and has nothing else installed. Not sure what else could be preventing this from working. Thanks for confirming that at least it's not a docker-compose/file/format issue.

Comment: I'm a bit older than you.  Docker version 1.12.6, build 78d18021ec,  docker-compose version 1.6.2, build 4d72027

Comment: well, one older, one newer.

Comment: Try to enter into the containers and ping either other while running.   I see so many questions where one could just jump inside and check things out.

Comment: It's difficult to get in there quickly because the web container kills itself after a few seconds of not being able to reach the mysql server. In any event, I did catch it once and received the typical "ping: unknown host"

Comment: Odd.   Using that v2 file you posted above -- mine ran until I killed it.

Comment: Reinstalled the OS. It must have been something in the "standard system utilities" group of packages since I installed that this time around but did not last time. I'm trying to narrow it down to a specific package just for posterity.

Comment: I reinstalled the OS a total of three times (minimal install with and without standard system utilities) and each time all the above docker-compose files all worked. I have no idea what was causing this to not work but apparently something odd/non-reproducible was messed up. Thanks for confirming the files do indeed work.